# How to get first value in PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have output Wordpress ACF field like this:

```
<?php the_field('price'); ?>
```

Result is this:

```
25000
```

That works very well, however I have problem when I put two values in Wordpress backend, result is like this:

```
250000 15000
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that I only output first value on the frontend. Idea is to achieve this:

```
250000
```

I try something like this:

```
  <?php $str1 = get_field('price'); $str2 = substr( $str1, 0, -4 ); echo $str2; ?>
```

I know that this is not solution, can I do it with Regex or can anybody help me with this? I'm new to PHP

Comment: While you're getting the answer to your specific question, I think a more "root" solution would be to explore different field types with ACF.  ACF supports a RICH variety of field types, and accessing them, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many solutions to get ist value, you can get by using `regex` like:

```
$str1 = '250000 15000';
preg_match('/\w+/', $str1, $result); // Test
echo $result[0]; //250000
```

Second solution is [`strtok()`](https://www.php.net/strtok) which is more faster then to [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$str1 = '250000 15000';
echo strtok($str1, " ");  //250000
```

[`Explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is an another option, which already posted in other answers.

Comment: Always learning from people on SO - never heard of or used strtok before this! Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Single line solution, break the string into an array of strings and then get the first element of the array, using null coalesce operator (php 7+) to avoid undefined index notice.

```
return explode(' ', get_field('price'))[0] ?? null;
```

Comment: Tip: [null coalesce operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) is PHP 7+....  Which you should be on... PHP 5.6 hasn't received security updates since Dec 2018....

Answer (score 1):

This is your variable.

`$price = the_field('price'); // which has value 250000 15000`

Then using php explode function, You can get first value.

`$priceSeperated = explode(' ', $price);`

`$priceSeperated = array_map('trim', $priceSeperated);`

Then check the value by var_dump or print_r

var_dump($priceSeperated);

Your output will be like this.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "250000"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "15000"
}
```

It will turn into an array, using explode function, So getting your first value, You can get it like this `$priceSeperated[0]` for second value `$priceSeperated[1]`, similarly if you have more values.

Note: the explode function will explode all the values after each space.

There is another PHP function **strtok()**, Example is give in other answers. 
 but explode() is much faster compared to strtok(). (Almost 5 times faster in small strings as well).

If you have memory-usage critical solution, you should keep in mind, that strtok function holds input string parameter (or reference to it?) in memory after usage.

Comment: Nice use of the `trim`.  You can never rely on content editors to not have stray spaces!

Answer (score 1):

All solutions presented so far rely on *valid input* into the ACF field.

What if the field is empty?
What is someone put in extra spaces, like `' 2500  1500 '`?
What if you DO want the second, third, or fourth value?

While one-liners are nice, functions can be just as nice.

```
function get_price( $price, $which = 0 ) {
    // explode on spaces
    $price = explode( ' ', $price );
    // // get rid of all extra spaces, such as in ' 2500  1500 '
    $price = array_filter( $price );
    // checks if the requested key exists, and returns it
    return ( array_key_exists( $which, $price ) ) ? $price[ $which ] : 0;
}

// usage:
echo get_price( ' 2500  1500 ', 0 ); // returns 2500
echo get_price( '2500 1500 ', 1 ); // returns 1500
echo get_price( '2500', 1 ); // returns 0
echo get_price( '2500 1500 1000 500', 3 ); // returns 500
```

Comment: nice and better modification but `regex` and `strtok` will generate first occurrence. my vote for u :)

Comment: @devpro - agreed, regex is even better, but I was considering OP's comment as a "PHP Beginner" - regexes can be rough for beginners (they were for me!)

Comment: yes, you are right, actually OP also mentioned `how can i do with regex` in question. it is good a beginner wants to learn this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$value= explode(" ",$price);
$last = $value[0];
```

It will work even if you put 3 or more, it will always bring the first one keeping `space` as the separator.

Comment: @cale_b you are are right, explode would place the same value at 0 index if there is no space. updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

this : [DOC](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php)

```
$outPut = '25000 15000';
$firstNumber = explode(' ', $outPut)[0];
```

Comment: `explode()` it once

Comment: I explode it once, the second one is just for info :D